# How to allow an input to be in lowercase and uppercase in python?

Tags: python

Here is my code. I'm trying to make a rock, paper, scissors game for a school project.

```
import random

choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

player_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?").lower()

while player_choice not in choices:
    player_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?").lower()

computer_choice = random.randint(0,2)
if computer_choice == 0:
    cpu_choice = choices[0]
elif computer_choice == 1:
    cpu_choice = choices[1]
elif computer_choice == 2:
    cpu_choice = choices[2]

print()
print("You play:", player_choice)
print("The computer plays:", cpu_choice)
print()

if player_choice == "Rock":
    if cpu_choice == choices[0]:
        print("Draw")
    elif cpu_choice == choices[1]:
        print("You Lose :((")
    else:
        print("You win!! :>>")
if player_choice == "Paper":
    if cpu_choice == choices[0]:
        print("You win!! :>>")
    elif cpu_choice == choices[1]:
        print("Draw")
    else:
        print("You Lose :((")
if player_choice == "Scissors":
    if cpu_choice == choices[0]:
        print("You Lose :((")
    elif cpu_choice == choices[1]:
        print("You Win!!! :>>")
    else:
        print("Draw")
```

The result you get is:
Rock, Paper, Scissors?rock
Rock, Paper, Scissors?Rock
Rock, Paper, Scissors?Rock

and it keeps going like this even though rock is part of choices. This also happens if I input scissors in lowercase or paper.

Comment: don't you need your if conditionals literals to be lower case? since you invoke lower on the user input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your input as well as the concerned comparing value into the same case whether it may be in lowercase or uppercase by using `.lower()` or `.upper()`.
Or while comparing like `if player_choice.lower() == 'rock'`,
`player_choice = player_choice.lower()`

Answer (score 1):

**Here is another approach that you could consider:**

If your `choices` options need to be capitalized, if you capitalize the `player_choice` input, the user's input would then be able to match the `choices` options. This can be done with [`capitalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=capitalize#str.capitalize).

Also, instead of having to worry about perfect uppercase or lowercase matching, you could try using regular expression matching using the `re` module. The matching could be done using [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) with a special flag called [`re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) that lets you ignore the case of the words that are being checked.

Additionally, it might be a good idea to use `elif:` statements after the first `if:` statement for this type of check.

I also added a space at the end of the initial input questions text for readability.

Here is an example of what these changes could look like:

```
import random
import re

choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

player_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? ").capitalize()

while player_choice not in choices:
    player_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? ").lower()

computer_choice = random.randint(0,2)
if computer_choice == 0:
    cpu_choice = choices[0]
elif computer_choice == 1:
    cpu_choice = choices[1]
elif computer_choice == 2:
    cpu_choice = choices[2]

print()
print("You play:", player_choice)
print("The computer plays:", cpu_choice)
print()

if re.match("rock", player_choice, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
    if cpu_choice == choices[0]:
        print("Draw")
    elif cpu_choice == choices[1]:
        print("You Lose :((")
    else:
        print("You win!! :>>")
elif re.match("Paper", player_choice, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
    if cpu_choice == choices[0]:
        print("You win!! :>>")
    elif cpu_choice == choices[1]:
        print("Draw")
    else:
        print("You Lose :((")
elif re.match("Scissors", player_choice, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
    if cpu_choice == choices[0]:
        print("You Lose :((")
    elif cpu_choice == choices[1]:
        print("You Win!!! :>>")
    else:
        print("Draw")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your condition literals to lower case:

`if player_choice == 'rock':`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

if player_choice.lower() == 'rock'

This will take the user input and lowercase everything in it.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to have both player and computer choose from the same set of values. The player enters values until they enter a valid choice. The computer uses `random.choice()` to select one of the choices from the valid list of choices. Note that you can lower case the possible selections in the valid list:

```
choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
```

Then it is easy to compare the computer and player selections by direct comparision. Here's code for the player and computer choices:

```
while True:
    player_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? ").lower()
    if player_choice in choices:
        break
    print("Invalid choice, try again.")

cpu_choice = random.choice(choices)

print()
print("You play:", player_choice)
print("The computer plays:", cpu_choice)
print()

if player_choice == cpu_choice:
    print("Draw")
elif player_choice == 'rock':
    if cpu_choice == 'paper':
        print("You Lose :((")
    else:
        print("You win!! :>>")
elif player_choice == 'paper':
    if cpu_choice == 'scissors':
        print("You Lose :((")
    else:
        print("You win!! :>>")
else:    # player chose scissors
    if cpu_choice == 'rock':
        print("You Lose :((")
    else:
        print("You win!! :>>")
```